# Making a table which is difference of 2 table by eliminating first char

Tags: sql, database, insert, substr, digit

I have 2 table as ebl_old and ebl. Both table has 1 column called imei. I have also an empty table called ebl_test. I want to add the rows which exists in ebl_old and not exists in ebl into ebl_test.

But my problem is: the data format in ebl_old and ebl is 15digit (starting with 0 and like 0xxxxxx...) and i want the data which will be added into ebl_test has format 14 digit (no 0 at the beggining)

when i execute :

```
insert into ebl_test
select * from ebl_old  a where not exists (select null from ebl  b where a.imei=b.imei)
```

it is adding the data with 0 at the beginning of them. How can eliminate that zero and make the data 14 digit instead of 15 digit ?

Comment: try Substring(YourColumn,1,14)

Comment: where to put substring in query?

Comment: Where you say "select * from"
instead list the columns like select a,b,Substring(C,1,14) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into ebl_test
select example1,
       example2,
       Substring(example3,1,14) --Lose the first character of example 3
from ebl_old a 
where not exists (select null from ebl  b where a.imei=b.imei)
```